# How to restrict NFC communication to only one screen in an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc

I'm working on a large app that wants to add NFC communication. This app has many manifests, one for the main shell app and one each for the many separate modules. Initially I registered the NFC service on the main manifest and it works fine. The issue is that the NFC service now triggers anytime the app is open and not when the user is on a specific screen.

So I wanted to ask, is there a way to have the NFC service register/un-register as a user navigates to/away from a specific screen? Or just a way to make it so that NFC communication is restricted to a specific screen? The size of this app is really tripping me up, I appreciate any help people can offer.

Comment: Do you want to have the feature of starting your App when it is not running when an NFC of the right type is presented to the Phone?

Comment: No not necessary. The user has to navigate to the specific screen themself.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not usual just to use manifest Intent filters for NFC operations though possible, usually one of the foreground API's is used instead.

The following solution works for API 19 upwards because it uses the `enableReaderMode` NFC API's because this is better and enables more control and is more reliable.

The basic concept is that in all `Activities` you claim to handle all NFC Tag types silently when the `Activity` is in the foreground, then for the `Activity` where you want the NFC reading to happen you actually do something when you are notified a Tag has been presented.

In your manifest you only have the following:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />`
and optionally
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`
for user feedback.

You don't have any of the NFC Intent filters.

The in every `Activity` you have the following boiler plate code:-

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback{
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
     
        // Rest of onCreate
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

       if(mNfcAdapter!= null) {
           Bundle options = new Bundle();
           options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);

           mNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this,
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK |
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
                options);

                // enabling FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK is optional
                // depending on if you are reading NDef data or not.
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mNfcAdapter!= null)
            mNfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
    }

    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag){
    // Do nothing when a NFC tag is detected

    }

}
```

In `Activities` where you want to handle the NFC Tag change `onTagDiscovered` method to do something with the Tag data.

e.g. for read Ndef data from a Tag `onTagDiscovered` could look like:-

```java
   // This method is run in another thread when a card is discovered
   // !!!! This method cannot cannot direct interact with the UI Thread
   // Use `runOnUiThread` method to change the UI from this method
   public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

      // Read and or write to Tag here to the appropriate Tag Technology type class
      // in this example the card should be an Ndef Technology Type 
      Ndef mNdef = Ndef.get(tag);

      // Check that it is an Ndef capable card
      if (mNdef!= null) {

          // If we want to read
          // As we did not turn on the NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK
          // We can get the cached Ndef message the system read for us.

          NdefMessage mNdefMessage = mNdef.getCachedNdefMessage();

          // Now your own code to process the Ndef message

          // Finally feedback to the user that the NFC read was a success
          // Make a Sound
          try {
              Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
              Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                  notification);
              r.play();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 // Some error playing sound
              }
          // Optionally Vibrate as well
          Vibrator v = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
          if (v != null) {
              v.vibrate(500);
          }
      }
  }
```

You can optionally you can also decide on when the NFC is handled when a particular `Fragment` is shown in your `Activity` or when a dialog is shown or any other state in your `Activity` by putting conditional clauses in your `onTagDiscovered` method.

e.g. Some pseudo code

```java
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

    if correct fragment is being shown {
        Handle NFC reading and feedback to user the NFC has been read
    } else {
    Do nothing
    }
}
```

or

```java
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

   if some condition is true {
       Handle NFC reading and feedback to user the NFC has been read
   } else {
   Do nothing
   }
}
```

Normally with Intent filter and `enableForegroundDisplatch` method of working with NFC the System service Handles the NFC event and notifies the user that an NFC card has been presented and then it interrupts you App by restarting the current `Activity` or starting another `Activity` from you App.

With `enableReadmode` and this method the NFC System Service is silent, because the Event is handled in another thread in your App, what the `Activity` currently is doing is not interrupted and you get full control about when you handle the NFC event or to silently ignore it.

The problem with any register/de-register approach is that the System NFC Service would always make a sound and possibly launch another App or display a default NFC content screen when you were de-registered.